# Marklogic How to use serialize

Tags: marklogic

How to use serialize to get 2000 documents in collection /user/bibliography,then use MLCP to export data.

```
let $query:=cts:and-query(cts:collection-query("/user/bibliography"))[1 to 2000]

let $serialize := xdmp:quote(
    <query>{$query}</query>/*, 
    <options xmlns="xdmp:quote"><indent>no</indent></options>
)
return $serialize
```

(:serialize return but it is not showing limit 1 to 2000 records.

```
   <cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"><cts:collection- 
       query><cts:uri>/user/bibliography</cts:uri></cts:collection-query> 
  </cts:and-query>
```

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query itself is just a description of the documents you want. In order to get those documents, you need to pass the query as an argument to the [`cts:search`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) function.

But you don't need to manually serialize documents if you are using MLCP, which automatically serializes documents when they are written to disk. Also, if you serialize twice, you may end up with double-encoded characters in your output.

If the reason you are serializing this query is to output everything in a single document, then wrap the results of `cts:search` in a root element and use `xdmp:document-insert` to insert the (not serialized) output into the database. Then use MLCP to export that. Otherwise, you don't need to write XQuery at all since you should be able to do everything in MLCP using collection filter and limit parameters.